Compose Scaffold does not get the max height of custom bottom bar
I have a custom bottom bar and i want Scaffold to get this bottomBar's max height and give  me the padding of it from the bottom so my content is properly placed when there is a scroll for example.
Currently my custom bottomBar and its layout is implemented like below:

@Composable
fun CurvedBottomBar() {
    val bottomBarWidth = getScreenSizeDp().screenWidth
    val curveHeight = 20.dp
    val bottomBarBackgroundColor = Color.Black
    val gradientColors =
        listOf(
            Color(0xFF4527A0),
            Color(0xFF4527A0),
        )
    CustomBottomNavigationLayout(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(bottomBarBackgroundColor)
            .drawBottomBarCurve(bottomBarBackgroundColor, gradientColors)
    ) {
        bottomBarItems.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
            if (index == 2) {

                CustomBottomNavItem(
                    icon = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = item.icon,
                            contentDescription = null,
                            tint = Color.White,
                            modifier = Modifier.size(90.dp)
                        )
                    },
                    label = null,
                    selected = true,
                    onClick = {
                    }
                )

            } else {
                CustomBottomNavItem(
                    icon = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = item.icon,
                            contentDescription = null,
                            tint = Color.White
                        )
                    },
                    label = item.titleResId,
                    selected = true,
                    onClick = {
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CustomBottomNavigationLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Layout(
        content = content,
        modifier = modifier
    ) { measurables, constraints ->

        val placeables =
            measurables.map {
                it.measure(constraints = constraints)
            }

        val gaps = calculateWeightedGap(placeables.map { it.width }, constraints.maxWidth)
        val otherItemsYPos = placeables.minOf { it.height } / 4

        layout(
            width = constraints.maxWidth,
            height = placeables.minOf { it.height } + 50 // Padding for icon texts
        ) {
            var xPos = gaps.first()
            placeables.forEachIndexed { index, placeable ->
                placeable.place(
                    x = if (index == 2) (constraints.maxWidth - placeable.width) / 2 else xPos,
                    y = if (index == 2) -placeable.height / 4 else otherItemsYPos
                )
                xPos += if (index == 2) placeable.width else placeable.width + gaps[index + 1]
            }
        }
    }
}

fun calculateWeightedGap(
    itemLengths: List<Int>,
    maxWidth: Int
): List<Int> {
    val allWidth = itemLengths.sumOf { it }
    val baseGap = (maxWidth - allWidth) / (itemLengths.size + 1)

    val gaps = mutableListOf(baseGap)

    for (itemLength in itemLengths) {
        val weight = itemLength.toFloat() / allWidth
        val gap = baseGap * (1.3 - weight)
        gaps.add(max(gap.toInt(), 0))
    }
    return gaps
}

fun Modifier.drawBottomBarCurve(
    bottomBarBackgroundColor: Color,
    gradientColors: List<Color>
) = drawWithCache {
    val bottomBarWidth = size.width
    val curveHeight = 20.dp
    val gradient = Brush.horizontalGradient(colors = gradientColors)
    val cp1 = Offset(bottomBarWidth * .38f, 0f)
    val cp2 = Offset(bottomBarWidth * .40f, -curveHeight.toPx())
    val cp3 = Offset(bottomBarWidth * .57f, -curveHeight.toPx())
    val cp4 = Offset(bottomBarWidth * .61f, 0f)
    onDrawBehind {
        val path =
            Path().apply {
                moveTo(0f, 0f)
                lineTo(bottomBarWidth * .32f, 0f)
                cubicTo(
                    x1 = cp1.x,
                    y1 = cp1.y,
                    x2 = cp2.x,
                    y2 = cp2.y,
                    x3 = bottomBarWidth / 2,
                    y3 = -curveHeight.toPx()
                )
                cubicTo(
                    x1 = cp3.x,
                    y1 = cp3.y,
                    x2 = cp4.x,
                    y2 = cp4.y,
                    x3 = bottomBarWidth * .68f,
                    y3 = 0f
                )
                lineTo(bottomBarWidth, 0f)
            }
        drawPath(
            path = path,
            color = bottomBarBackgroundColor
        )
        drawPath(
            path = path,
            brush = gradient,
            style = Stroke(5f)
        )
    }
}

val bottomBarItems =
    listOf(
        BottomNavItem.Home,
        BottomNavItem.Operations,
        BottomNavItem.Add,
        BottomNavItem.Profile,
        BottomNavItem.Menu
    )

sealed class BottomNavItem(
    val route: String,
    val titleResId: String,
    val icon: ImageVector
) {
    object Home : BottomNavItem(
        route = Screen.Home.route,
        titleResId = "Home",
        icon = Icons.Default.Home
    )

    object Menu : BottomNavItem(
        route = Screen.Search.route,
        titleResId = "Search",
        icon = Icons.Default.Menu
    )

    object Operations : BottomNavItem(
        route = Screen.Search.route,
        titleResId = "Search",
        icon = Icons.Default.DateRange
    )

    object Profile : BottomNavItem(
        route = Screen.Search.route,
        titleResId = "Search",
        icon = Icons.Default.Person
    )

    object Add : BottomNavItem(
        route = Screen.Search.route,
        titleResId = "Add",
        icon = Icons.Default.Add
    )
}

@Composable
fun CustomBottomNavItem(
    icon: @Composable () -> Unit,
    label: String?,
    selected: Boolean = false,
    onClick: () -> Unit = {}
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = onClick),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        icon()
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
        if (label != null)
            Text(text = label, color = Color.White)
    }
}



And usage:
                Scaffold(
                    bottomBar = {
                        CurvedBottomBar()
                    }
                ) { scaffoldPadding ->
                    Column(
                        Modifier
                            .padding(scaffoldPadding)
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    ) {
                        repeat(50) {
                            Card(
                                onClick = { },
                                shape = RectangleShape
                            ) {
                                Text(text = "Item $it")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

Result of this is:

As you can see last several items are not shown because of the bottomBars curve.
How can i make scaffold to get actual height of my CustomBottomBar ?
